# Is it possible to add a function to expand and/or collapse all accordion in a click?

Tags: javascript, accordion

I'm currently setting up an FAQ page and I need to add a function to expand/collapse all answers in a click of a button. If expand link/button is clicked, it will show all contents of the accordion and then, the label 'Expand All' will be replaced with 'Collapse All' and the function will be vice versa.

I'm not sure if tweaking the current JS will do.

```
//hides a accordion panel
function close(opts) {
    opened = $(document).find('.' + opts.cssOpen);
    $.each(opened, function() {
        //give the proper class to the linked element
        $(this).addClass(opts.cssClose).removeClass(opts.cssOpen);
        opts.animateClose($(this), opts);
    });
}

//opens a accordion panel
function open($this, opts) {
    close(opts);
    //give the proper class to the linked element
    $this.removeClass(opts.cssClose).addClass(opts.cssOpen);

    //open the element
    opts.animateOpen($this, opts);

    //do cookies if plugin available
    if (useCookies(opts)) {
        // split the cookieOpen string by ","
        id = $this.attr('id');
        setCookie(id, opts);
    }
}

//toggle a accordion on an event
function toggle($this, opts) {
    // close the only open item
    if ($this.hasClass(opts.cssOpen))
    {
        close(opts);
        //do cookies if plugin available
        if (useCookies(opts)) {
            // split the cookieOpen string by ","
            setCookie('', opts);
        }
        return false;
    }
    close(opts);
    //open a closed element
    open($this, opts);
    return false;
}
```

Expected results will be similar to https://www.gucci.com/int/en/st/faq

Comment: The current page I'm working on is at https://shopatforest.com/pages/accordion-test-page

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same functionality using jquery and bootstrap code below:

**html code**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="accordion-option">
    <h3 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle-accordion active" accordion-id="#accordion"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit,
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
body {
  color: #6a6c6f;
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e4e5e7;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  float: right;
  transition: transform .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\2212";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\002b";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.accordion-option {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.accordion-option .title {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6a6c6f;
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion:before {
  content: "Expand All";
}

.accordion-option .toggle-accordion.active:before {
  content: "Collapse All";
}
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".toggle-accordion").on("click", function() {
    var accordionId = $(this).attr("accordion-id"),
      numPanelOpen = $(accordionId + ' .collapse.in').length;

    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    if (numPanelOpen == 0) {
      openAllPanels(accordionId);
    } else {
      closeAllPanels(accordionId);
    }
  })

  openAllPanels = function(aId) {
    console.log("setAllPanelOpen");
    $(aId + ' .panel-collapse:not(".in")').collapse('show');
  }
  closeAllPanels = function(aId) {
    console.log("setAllPanelclose");
    $(aId + ' .panel-collapse.in').collapse('hide');
  }

});
```

You have to use bootstarp 3.3.6 for the given code, These code used in my old project In which I have used bootstrap 3.3.6, Or you can modify for bootstrap 4.

**Bootstrap css link:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**jQuery and bootstrap js link**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried implementing the codes above on the actual page but it seems something's wrong and I don't know what. See https://shopatforest.com/pages/accordion-test-page

Comment: The issue is bootstrap css conflict with you shopify css, For the same funcationality, You need to change bootstrap panel code html with you shopify html panel code, because shopify having its own code for panel you have to use with them, And you will got the same functionality with the same

Comment: You can you to open all panel by below code, but js off shopify will close all even click on one, so please modify that:


**Code**

`
function openAllPanels() {
    console.log("setAllPanelOpen");
    $(`.accordion.accordion-close+div`).show();
    $(`.accordion.accordion-close`).removeClass('accordion-close').addClass('accordion-open');
}
`

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit lost...

1. How to change bootstrap's panel code html with Shopify's?
2. To open all panel at once, do I just need to add the above function?

I've setup a demo page with the base html/css/js codes above and can be viewed at https://forestdev4.myshopify.com/pages/accordion-test

Storefront password: accordion123